# pausing main thread will async function runs swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, firebase-realtime-database

I call the following function in a while loop but the asynchronous code doesn't run even with the dispatch_group being used.  Does anyone know what I may be doing incorrectly?  *I am trying to essentially get the while loop to wait for the asynchronous code to be executed before continuing.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if(ended != true) {
        if(count2 < 2) {
            print("current count is < 2")

        } else {
            var playRef = ref.child("LiveGames").child("05-25-17").child("RedSox")

            asyncCall(playRef, ended: ended, count: count2)

            }
            print("successful delay")
            count2++

            //playIsntThere()

        }//this is where the else loop ends

        count2++
    }



 func asyncCall(ref:FIRDatabaseReference, ended:Bool, count:Int) {
        var count2 = count

        let myGroup = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(myGroup)

        ref.child(String(count2-2)).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2) in
            var hitterRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Hitter")
            var pitcherRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Pitcher")

            pitcherEra.text = String(pitcherRef.childSnapshotForPath("/ERA").value!)
        })
        dispatch_group_leave(myGroup)


        dispatch_group_notify(myGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("code completed")
        }
        print("successful delay")
        count2++
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code that calls `asyncCall`.

Comment: Your question mentions a `while` loop. But there's no loop of any kind in the code you posted. And unrelate - you should call `super.viewDidAppear` in your `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I have switched `while(ended != true)` to `if(ended != true)` to run only once for testing purposes.

Comment: You need to move the call to `dispatch_group_leave(myGroup)` to be inside the completion block of the call to `ref.child`.